# Complex ng-table poor performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I've got some problems with poor performance of big, complex ng-table. I've got 13 columns with 25 rows. But each row has one nested table with 7 columns and at average 25 rows. The key thing is that I've also got a lot of filters and ng-ifs placed all around these tables. Everything would be all right except I want to apply columns selection. These things combined makes UX really poor as it freezes the whole browser while toggling this column for about 5-7 seconds. My question is: How to reduce time to render this last column? Are there any tricks that can speed it up?

I've prepared simple demo of my problem. It's really simple and doesn't have all of my filters, ng-ifs, etc. But it shows code schema and issue that I've faced recently.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngTable"]);
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "ngTableParams", function MyController($scope, ngTableParams) {
  // Prepare data
  $scope.data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var list = [];
    for (var t = 1; t <= 25; t++) {
      list.push({
        col1: i*10+t,
        col2: i*10+t,
        col3: i*10+t,
        col4: i*10+t,
        col5: i*10+t,
        col6: i*10+t,
        col7: i*10+t
      })
    }
    $scope.data.push({
      col1: 'Col1 value',
      col2: 'Col2 value',
      col3: 'Col3 value',
      col4: 'Col4 value',
      col5: 'Col5 value',
      col6: 'Col6 value',
      col7: 'Col7 value',
      col8: 'Col8 value',
      col9: 'Col9 value',
      col10: 'Co10 value',
      col11: 'Col11 value',
      col12: 'Col12 value',
      col13: list
    });
  }
  
  // Prepare tables
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    count: $scope.data.length
  }, {
    total: $scope.data.length,
    counts: [],
    getData: function($defer, params) {
      $defer.resolve($scope.data);
    }
  });
}]);
app.filter('demoFilter', function() {
  return function(data) {
    // Simulate some work that has to be done in each row
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++);
    return data;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="ng-table@0.8.3" data-semver="0.8.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ng-table@0.8.3" data-semver="0.8.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Ng-table example</h2>
      <button ng-click="showLastColumn = !showLastColumn">Toggle last column</button>
      <table class="table table-striped" ng-table="tableParams">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td data-title="'Col1'" ng-if="true">{{row.col1 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col2'" ng-if="true">{{row.col2 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col3'" ng-if="true">{{row.col3 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col4'" ng-if="true">{{row.col4 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col5'" ng-if="true">{{row.col5 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col6'" ng-if="true">{{row.col6 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col7'" ng-if="true">{{row.col7 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col8'" ng-if="true">{{row.col8 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col9'" ng-if="true">{{row.col9 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col10'" ng-if="true">{{row.col10 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col11'" ng-if="true">{{row.col11 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Col12'" ng-if="true">{{row.col12 | demoFilter}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Nested'" ng-if="showLastColumn">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nested Col1</th>
                  <th>Nested Col2</th>
                  <th>Nested Col3</th>
                  <th>Nested Col4</th>
                  <th>Nested Col5</th>
                  <th>Nested Col6</th>
                  <th>Nested Col7</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="elem in row.col13">
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col1 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col2 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col3 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col4 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col5 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col6 | demoFilter}}</td>
                  <td ignore-cell="true" ng-if="true">{{elem.col7 | demoFilter}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, there is Plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/y2kP7balBVn8ioP7pOIa?p=preview

I'm using Angular v.1.3.8 and ng-table v.0.8.3.